# Select null if record doens't exist mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select a value from a **third_table** where ***something*** from the **first_table** *equals* another thing from the **third_table**. This last value from the third table **might not exist!**

I have the following mysql query:

```
$query = "SELECT ft.value1, ft.value2, st.value3, st.value4, tt.valueWantedMightNotExist 
          FROM first_table ft, second_table st, third_table tt 
          WHERE ft.value5 = st.value5" AND ft.something = tt.anothersomething;
```

This query returns results **only** if the value exists. Otherwise it returns nothing. I tried this with `FULL JOIN`as well but ended messing up as well. Can someone explain to me how can I return a null value if the record doesn't exist? Thank you very much...

Comment: What does that quotation mark do? And how do these tables relate to one another? I think you need to start with a simple introduction to PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get rows with no match.

```
SELECT ft.value1, ft.value2, st.value3, st.value4, tt.valueWantedMightNotExist
FROM first_table ft
INNER JOIN second_table st ON ft.value5 = st.value5
LEFT JOIN third_table tt ON ft.something = tt.anothersomething
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to change the whole syntax of the query? Can't I maintain it similar and just add LEFT JOIN in the end?

Comment: No, it's not. But you should learn to write ANSI JOIN and forget about the old implicit joins.

Comment: I DID IT BARMAR. TYVM MA MAN

Answer (score 3):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`. This will do exactly what you want.

By default, (i.e., if you just use a comma,) you get an `INNER JOIN`, which will give you rows only when they match on both sides; but a `LEFT JOIN` will give you everything on the left, and nulls on the right where there's no match.

There's also a `RIGHT JOIN`, the purpose of which is left as an exercise for the astute reader :)

You should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins). The top-voted answer uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but in MySQL at least, the `OUTER` has no effect. And the second-highest answer has a pretty picture that's rather helpful for the intuition.